# Difference between h:selectOneMenu vs rich:comboBox

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, richfaces

What is difference between `h:selectOneMenu` and `rich:comboBox` component?

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userData.data}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Item 1" />
       <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Item 2" />                                
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <rich:comboBox defaultLabel="Enter some value">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="item 1"/>
       <f:selectItem itemValue="item 2"/>
    </rich:comboBox>
```

Comment: Just run them both and compare?

Comment: Or look at the documentation and showcase of each of them...

Answer (score 2):

`rich:comboBox` component is part of [RichFaces 3](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.4.Final/en/tlddoc/) and does not exist in RichFaces 4.

In RichFaces 3 `rich:comboBox` is component that allows to create a combobox element with the built-in Ajax capability. In RichFaces 4 for that purpose is used `h:selectOneMenu`. Example from [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=ajax&sample=selectsUpdates&skin=blueSky):

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}" valueChangeListener="#{selectsBean.valueChanged}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.firstList}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```